# jaaslounge spnego/kerberos ticket decryption aes-256

Tags: aes, kerberos, spnego

has anyone done this with jaas lounge and aes256-cts? jaaslounge KerberosEncData does not seem to have any implementation for this type of encryption.

has anyone out there hacked together a working decryptor for aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96?

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this already before. Search for please. You need unlimited strength policy for Java.